# Take query results and insert into new table

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, subquery, query-performance

So I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(value int)

*--The same function but with the number of the random numbers
;WITH Nbrs (n) AS (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 6 )
INSERT INTO @tbl
(
    value
)
SELECT
    Nbrs.n AS Sequence
FROM Nbrs 
;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT CAST(1 as BIGINT) UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 480000)
SELECT
    tblOrderRandomNumbers.[1] AS First,
    tblOrderRandomNumbers.[2] AS Second,
    tblOrderRandomNumbers.[3] AS Third,
    tblOrderRandomNumbers.[4] AS Fourth,
    tblOrderRandomNumbers.[5] AS Fifth,
    tblOrderRandomNumbers.[6] AS Sixth
FROM
    Nbrs
    --This cross join. Joins with the declared table
    CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]
            FROM
            (
            SELECT
                Random,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY tblRandom.Random ASC) AS RowNumber
            FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 49 + 1) AS Random
                FROM
                    @tbl AS tblNumbers
                ) AS tblRandom
            )AS tblSortedRadom
            --A pivot makes the rows to columns. Using the row index over order of the random number
            PIVOT
            (
                AVG(Random)
            FOR RowNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4],[5],[6])
            ) as pivottable
        ) AS tblOrderRandomNumbers
OPTION ( MAXRECURSION 0 )*
```

I would like to automatically insert these results into a table, anyone have some advice?

Comment: As an aside, there are much more efficient ways to generate sets like this than recursive CTEs - see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1, http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2 and http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to insert into a new table that has already been created, you can say:

```
    ;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT CAST(1 as BIGINT) UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 480000)

    INSERT dbo.ExistingTable(First,Second,Third,Fourth,Fifth,Sixth)
----^^^^^^ this line

    SELECT
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[1] AS First,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[2] AS Second,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[3] AS Third,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[4] AS Fourth,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[5] AS Fifth,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[6] AS Sixth
    FROM
     Nbrs
    ...
```

If you trying to create a new table based on the output, you can say:

```
    ;WITH Nbrs ( n ) AS (
        SELECT CAST(1 as BIGINT) UNION ALL
        SELECT 1 + n FROM Nbrs WHERE n < 480000)
    SELECT
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[1] AS First,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[2] AS Second,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[3] AS Third,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[4] AS Fourth,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[5] AS Fifth,
     tblOrderRandomNumbers.[6] AS Sixth

    INTO dbo.NewTable
----^^^^^^ this line

    FROM
     Nbrs
    ...
```